# Arranging multidimensional array in a certain format in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a array in below format

```
Array
(
    [title] => Array
        (
            [0] => Ram 
            [1] => ramesh
            [2] => john
            [3] => mahesh

        )

    [neighborhood] => Array
        (
            [0] => delhi
            [1] => mumbai
            [2] => odisha
            [3] => banglore

        )



    [phone_no] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  9438648-4256
            [1] => 9438333-3390
            [2] => 9438771-0888
            [3] => 9438504-7000

        )
)
```

but i want in such format given below

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Ram 
            [neighborhood] => delhi
            [phone_no] =>  9438648-4256

        )

        [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => Ramesh 
            [neighborhood] => mumbai
            [phone_no] => 9438333-3390 

        )


        [2] => Array
        (
            [title] => john 
            [neighborhood] => odisha
            [phone_no] =>  9438771-0888

        )

        [3] => Array
        (
            [title] => mahesh 
            [neighborhood] => banglore
            [phone_no] => 9438504-7000

        )
}
```

I want the the array in above format in php.Any help is highly appreciated .
Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome. Have you tried anything so far? Where do you fail? Can we see your code?

Comment: I am new to php and getting no idea how to do it.

Comment: @prabhatkumarjena Please try re-phrasing your question to show an example of what you have tried and some of your code. It would make it easier for us to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`array_combine()` and `array_column()` make clear code for this task.  The `for` loop will iterate for each column in the multi-dimensional array.  Then simply pair-up the array keys with the column values using `array_combine()`.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b7cf40b444e94b14db813fd20819f197372f0f61))

```
$array=[
    'title'=>['Ram','ramesh','john','mahesh'],
    'neighborhood'=>['delhi','mumbai','odisha','banglore'],
    'phone_no'=>['9438648-4256','9438333-3390','9438771-0888','9438504-7000']
];

$keys=array_keys($array);  // cache the array keys
$columns=sizeof($array['title']); // cache the number of columns to iterate
for($c=0; $c<$columns; ++$c){
    $result[]=array_combine($keys,array_column($array,$c));
}

var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'title' => 'Ram',
    'neighborhood' => 'delhi',
    'phone_no' => '9438648-4256',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'title' => 'ramesh',
    'neighborhood' => 'mumbai',
    'phone_no' => '9438333-3390',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'title' => 'john',
    'neighborhood' => 'odisha',
    'phone_no' => '9438771-0888',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'title' => 'mahesh',
    'neighborhood' => 'banglore',
    'phone_no' => '9438504-7000',
  ),
)
```

---

Alternatively, you could use a `foreach` loop like this:

```
$keys=array_keys($array);  // cache the array keys
foreach($array['title'] as $i=>$v){
    $result[]=array_combine($keys,array_column($array,$i));
}
```

`$v` is declared but not used so that `$i` can be declared.

Answer (score 1):

```
  $arr = array(
    "title" => array("t1","t2","t3","t4"),
    "neighborhood" => array("n1","n2","n3","n4"),
    "phone_no" => array("p1","p2","p3","p4"),

);

$keys = array_keys($arr);
$child_len = count($arr[ $keys[0] ]);

$returnArr = array();

for ($i=0; $i < $child_len; $i++) { 
    $returnArr[$i] = array();
    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        $returnArr[$i][$key] = $arr[$key][$i];
    }

}
var_dump($returnArr);
```

not the most effective , but will work for you

out would be like

```
[0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(2) "t1"
    ["neighborhood"]=>
    string(2) "n1"
    ["phone_no"]=>
    string(2) "p1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(2) "t2"
    ["neighborhood"]=>
    string(2) "n2"
    ["phone_no"]=>
    string(2) "p2"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(2) "t3"
    ["neighborhood"]=>
    string(2) "n3"
    ["phone_no"]=>
    string(2) "p3"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(3) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(2) "t4"
    ["neighborhood"]=>
    string(2) "n4"
    ["phone_no"]=>
    string(2) "p4"
  }
```